# DBT docs generate - Override the default overview page with custom content in the documentation website

Tags: web, model, documentation, dbt, fishtown-analytics

I am using the dbt docs generate for generating my project's documentation website. I want to override the default overview page with my own custom content in the website. Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [the docs](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/building-a-dbt-project/documentation):

> The "overview" shown in the documentation website can be overridden by supplying your own docs block called `__overview__`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It solved my problem

Comment: Can you help me with the process to change the default title and the dbt logo generated by default documentation?